# How to intercept/edit the_category?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In WordPress functions.php, how would I grab the_category() output before it displays and unset some number of categories and URLs in its output?

I use some number of categories to help organize my category structure, to make it easier to find and use categories when creating content. But I don't want these "helper" categories to display wherever the_category() is called in my site.

Because the number of these helper categories is large and somewhat likely to expand, while the descriptive categories I want to use and display is a small data set, ideally I'd like to grab the_category() results before it is displayed, in the functions.php file, and remove any categories not defined. So I might have an array of 10 descriptive category names and their URLs. Then do a comparison with the_category() data and remove any category names and URLs from the_category() output NOT in my array of 10 categories.

Is this do-able? Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

My apologies for posting in the wrong spot. Don't know what prevented me thinking of StackEXCHANGE instead of StackOverflow:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/31181/exclude-categories-from-the-category

This question is answered.